# Kann/soll nach "derartig" ein Komma stehen?

Tags: comma

Ich stolpere gerade beim Korrekturlesen über einen Satz ähnlich wie der folgende:

**Beispiel:**

> Derartige, sich am wahren Leben kaum orientierende Beispielsätze sind entweder richtig oder haben möglicherwise ein Komma zu viel.

Ist hier ein Komma hinter *Derartige* wirklich richtig (möglich/erforderlich), weil es halt ein Adjektiv ist und basta?

Oder  soll/muss man lieber kein Komma setzen, weil es semantisch fast wie ein Demonstrativpronomen oder gar Artikel wirkt?

Comment: Was mich am Beispielsatz stört, ist, dass auf jeden Fall ein Komma nach *Beispielsätze* fehlt. Dieses ist zwingend, wenn schon nach *derartige* eines steht und damit den Einschub *sich am wahren Leben kaum orientierende Beispielsätze* isoliert.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann fast richtig - das Komma muss zwischen *orientierende* und *Beispielsätze*

Comment: Nur so ebenbei, _derartig, dass_ leitet ebenfalls einen Einschubsatz ein.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf   Derartige, auf Flüchtigkeit beruhende, Fehler passieren mir leider immer.

Answer (score 2):

> Derartige, sich für das wahre Leben kaum interessierende, dicke Frösche ...

Würdest du dort ein Komma setzen? Ich schon. Da es sich bezüglich der Satzstruktur um dasselbe in grün handelt, würde ich auch dort das Komma setzen.

Anders wäre es bei dem Satz

> Sich derartig am wahren Leben kaum orientierende Beispielsätze ...

Aber das ist wohl nicht gemeint. Ansonsten könnte man das ja auch so schreiben.

Comment: Ich bin eben auch (vielleicht nur, weil ich jetzt zu lange darüber nachdenke) bei deinem Froschbeispiel unschlüssig. Aber am Ende stimmt es wohl einfach ... :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Wer kennt das nicht! Wenn man zu lange grübelt, weiß man am Ende nicht mehr, wie Apfel geschrieben wird. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wie Christian Geiselmann in seinem Kommentar schon schreibt, ist das Komma dort nicht nur richtig, es *fehlt* ein weiteres Komma.
Der Satz ohne Einschub würde lauten

> Derartige Beispielsätze sind entweder richtig oder haben möglicherwise ein Komma zu viel.

Dann gibt es einen erläuternden Einschub

> sich am wahren Leben kaum orientierende

Dieser Einschub ist ein Relativsatz und muss vorne und hinten Durch Kommata vom Hauptsatz getrennt werden:

> Derartige, sich am wahren Leben kaum orientierende, Beispielsätze sind entweder richtig oder haben möglicherwise ein Komma zu viel.

Comment: Und was, wenn ich das nicht als Einschub, sondern als Aufzählung ansehe?

Comment: @CarstenS Passt hier zumindest inhaltlich nicht. Das *sich am wahren Leben kaum orientierende* ist eine Erläuterung, um welchen Aspekt es bei *derartig* geht. Es ist **keine** Aufzählung im Sinne von *erstens derartig und zweitens sich am wahren Leben orientierende*. Aber selbst in Fällen mit anderem Inhalt, wo es eine Aufzählung wäre, müssten dann die beiden aufgezählten Elemente entweder ein *und* oder ein Komma zwischen sich haben.